# How to determine the active control within a tabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, tabcontrol, contextmenustrip

I have a tab control through which the user can right-click within one of several richTextBoxes. The textBoxes use the same contextMenuStrip control, and I need to determine which textBox is the active one within the `contextMenuStripCopyPaste_Opening` event. I would think that the code to determine this would be
`tabControl1.SelectedTab.ActiveControl.Name` but the `ActiveControl` property is not available. `this.ActiveControl.Name` just gives me the name of the tabControl.

How can I determine which textBox is the active control within the tabControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sender` paramter to get the `ContextMenuStrip` then call the `ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl` property to get the control that opened the context menu.

In this case you can try the following code.

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var ctxStrip = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
    if (ctxStrip == null)
        return;

    var rtb = ctxStrip.SourceControl as RichTextBox;
    if (rtb == null)
        return;
}
```

This code simply casts the `sender` object to a `ContextMenuStrip` if this is `null` then return. (Although should never be). The next line captures the `SourceControl` and casts the control to a `RichTextBox`.

If the source control is not a `RichTextBox` then the result will be null and we cancel as this shouldn't be null unless you bind the context menu to other controls aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not finding anything that is there by default. I would create a list of the rich text boxes, and then use a LINQ statement as the LINQ Select statement would return only the rich text box that has the focus. Something like this.

List rtbList = new List {RichTextBox1, RichTextBox2, RichTextBox3, RichTextBox4}

var FocusedRTB = rtbList.Select(x => x.Focused == true);

switch (FocusedRTB.Name)

{Execute Code for each RichTextBox
}